# Dynamic content replacement in Laravel with masks

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

I am updating a custom CMS from CodeIgniter to Laravel. It uses custom masks (currently in single curly brackets) that allows *user entered* content to be dynamically updated with values entered elsewhere.

Codeigniter gave a neat way of doing this where the the page parser could be passed an associative array (such as favouritefruit=>'Apple') - this would then replace all the relevant masks *on the entire page* just prior to output. This meant masks could be used anywhere.

Trying to find a neat way of doing this in Laravel 4.2. I could ->render() the view to a variable and str_replace prior to the controller returning it, but wondering if there is a 'native' way perhaps using Blade.

In short I am trying to run mask replacement twice on the same data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string replace on the whole view is pretty easy actually. Just call `render()` and you get the view string:

```
$view = View::make('view.name')->render();
$view = str_replace('{mask}', 'value', $view);
return $view;
```

Comment: I know how to echo out a variable with Blade - I want to know how to update a mask in THAT variable, ie can Laravel do another pass on the echoed data to update other masks that it may contain.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly but maybe you can run it through a custom function? like `{{ replaceMasks($foo) }}`

Comment: Ideally I want to be able to do that on the entire content of the page - I've amended the question to reflect this... CI gave a neat, native way of doing it, just wondering if Laravel has same.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, that would do it but just wondering if there is a 'native' solution within Laravel, as doing this is processor/memory intensive on larger pages.

Comment: No not really. I guess you could replace the values in your string *before* actually rendering the view. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: If you are referring to "partials", I did something similar with this package (so certainly not native), but it is for L4 and hasn't been updated in a while: [link](https://github.com/conarwelsh/mustache-l4)